# Faster Database WHERE for Rails Availability Calendar

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Ruby on Rails hostel bed reservation system and I'm looking for a better way to load my availability calendar. The below code works great for showing bed availability (see attached image), but I feel like the multiple WHERE database calls are too taxing on the server and there must be a quicker way to process the data.

**Models:**

user.rb

bed.rb (user_id, name)

guest.rb (user_id, name, phone, address, email)

reservation.rb (user_id, bed_id, guest_id, date)

Users are hostel owners. They create as many beds as their business has and give them a name (Bed #1, Bed #2, Twin-Attic, Master-2nd Floor, etc).

Each user has many guests, these are people sleeping at their hostel on a specific date.

Using the simple_calendar gem, I get all reservations for the current month and process them to show a weekly view.

**Sorting logic:**

**Step 1.** Iterate through current_user's beds for the first day of the week.(simple_calendar supplies each day's reservations)

**Step 2.** If the bed has a reservation for that day(!= nil), put bed name and the name of the guest for that reservation.

**Step 3.** If the bed doesn't have a reservation, put bed name and 'Empty.'

**Step 4.** After completing the first day of week, move to next day and repeat.(simple_calendar takes care of this)

As I said, the code below works, but when a user has 50 beds, it makes 50 WHERE calls for each day, so 350 for a 7-day calendar (and more if it needs to find the guest's name).

Please let me know if you need any more information or explanations. Thanks!

```
= week_calendar events: @monthly_reservations, attribute: :date do |date, appts|
  - current_user.beds.each do |bed|
    - if bed.reservations.where(date: date).first != nil
      - guest_name = bed.reservations.where(date: date).first.guest.abbreviated_name
        %p{style: "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; font-size: 10px;"}
          = "#{bed.name}: #{guest_name}"
    - else
      %p{style: "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; font-size: 10px;"}
        = "#{bed.name}: Empty"
```

[CURRENT Rails hostel bed reservation system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGFeZ.png)

**EDIT:**
The ideal calendar layout would look like the image below:

[IDEAL Rails bed reservation system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGP7F.png)

However, the problem is making the bed name line up with the correct bed reservation. If May 2 has only 2 reservations, Bed 1 and Bed 4, the code doesn't know to leave two EMPTYS before inserting Bed 4's appointment last. Make sense?

**EDIT #2:**

@DavidAldridge, something like this:

Something like this?

`reservs = {"[2017-05-01, bed_1]" => "guest_23", "[2017-05-01, bed_2]" => "empty"}`

**EDIT 3**
Here is what the logs look like when loading a hostel with just 5 beds.

```
Bed Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "beds".* FROM "beds" WHERE "beds"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 1], ["date", "2017-07-02"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 2], ["date", "2017-07-02"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 3], ["date", "2017-07-02"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 4], ["date", "2017-07-02"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 5], ["date", "2017-07-02"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 1], ["date", "2017-07-03"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 2], ["date", "2017-07-03"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 3], ["date", "2017-07-03"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 4], ["date", "2017-07-03"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 5], ["date", "2017-07-03"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 1], ["date", "2017-07-04"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 2], ["date", "2017-07-04"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 3], ["date", "2017-07-04"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 4], ["date", "2017-07-04"]]
  Reservations Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 5], ["date", "2017-07-04"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 1], ["date", "2017-07-05"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 2], ["date", "2017-07-05"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 3], ["date", "2017-07-05"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 4], ["date", "2017-07-05"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 5], ["date", "2017-07-05"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 1], ["date", "2017-07-06"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 2], ["date", "2017-07-06"]]
  Reservations Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 3], ["date", "2017-07-06"]]
  Reservations Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 4], ["date", "2017-07-06"]]
  Reservations Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 5], ["date", "2017-07-06"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 1], ["date", "2017-07-07"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 2], ["date", "2017-07-07"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 3], ["date", "2017-07-07"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 4], ["date", "2017-07-07"]]
  Reservations Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 5], ["date", "2017-07-07"]]
  Reservations Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 1], ["date", "2017-07-08"]]
  Reservations Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 2], ["date", "2017-07-08"]]
  Reservations Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 3], ["date", "2017-07-08"]]
  Reservations Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 4], ["date", "2017-07-08"]]
  Reservations Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."bed_id" = $1 AND "reservations"."date" = $2  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bed_id", 5], ["date", "2017-07-08"]]
```

**EDIT 4**
Following @DavidAldridge suggestion, I created a hash in the controller and passed it into my view. The results are STELLAR!

Controller code:

```
@reservations = {}

@monthly_reservations.each do |x|
  @reservations[[x.date,x.bed_id]] = x.guest.try(:name)  
end
```

And the view code:

```
= week_calendar events: @monthly_reservations, attribute: :date do |date, appts|
  - current_user.beds.each do |bed|
    - if @reservations[[date, bed.id]] != nil
      %p{style: "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; font-size: 10px;"}
        = "#{bed.name}: #{@reservations[[date, kennel.id]]}"
    - else
      %p{style: "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; font-size: 10px;"}
        = "#{bed.name}:"
```

Comment: "I feel like the multiple WHERE database calls are too taxing on the server". This is intuition, which may or may not be correct. The only way to find out is to look closely at `log/development.log` to see how your queries are performing. It's generally a good idea to keep `tail -f log/development.log` open in a window *at all times* to get a feel for how efficient or ugly your code is as you load pages and develop features.

Comment: Why not just query your table once, to get all the records for the current_user in the current month, and then iterate over the results?

Comment: That's exactly what the @monthly_reservations variable contains, all the current_user's reservations for that month.

However, the WHEREs come in because I need to show all the beds that the hostel has, and then who, if anyone, is staying in said bed.

Tadman, I completely agree about the intuition part. Maybe it ISN'T taxing the server, but when I look at the logs and see the never ending WHEREs every time the page loads, it worries me.

Comment: You ought to be able to run a single query that gets bed, date, and user, and construct a hash from that with a key of `[bed,date]` and value of `guest`. Then you can iterate through your beds and dates in whichever order make most sense to you, looking up any guest from the hash for each date/bed combination.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, I think that sounds like a great idea. I just needed some extra brainpower to help me think of other possible ways. My code works, but it's smelly.

Comment: @PatrickJones Yes, that's the stuff.

Comment: @tadman, please see EDIT 3 above to see the logs.For that one page load, I'm getting these results: `Completed 200 OK in 102ms (Views: 78.9ms | ActiveRecord: 9.0ms)`

Comment: @DavidAldridge, please create an answer. I'd like to upvote it. Your suggestion shaved off 6ms and removed ALL the WHERE queries.

Answer (score 1):

What Robbie is describing is capturing the data in bulk to present it in a second pass. You can do this:

```
@reservations = Reservations.where(bed_id: [ ... ], date: (from..to)).group_by do |r|
  [r.bed_id, r.date]
end
```

Where this returns a singular structure that should contain all the reservations in a way that can be easily indexed using both `bed_id` and a date. You can turn this into a two-tier structure if necessary, but it's usually not.

When iterating:

```
- current_user.beds.each do |bed|
  - reservation = @reservations[[bed.id,date]]
  - if reservation
    # ...
```

This practice of selectively, but aggressively eager-loading records usually works quite well when you're dealing with complex inter-dependencies that can't be easily expressed with an `includes(..)` element in your loading chain.

Also, remember in Ruby there's only two things that are logically false: literal `false` and `nil`. Everything else evaluates as logically true, including 0, empty strings, arrays and hashes. As such comparisons `!= nil` are almost always extraneous and confusing, especially if you do double-negation like `unless (x != nil)`.

If you're looking to be able to resolve a number of arbitrary date+bed pairs against the database you could make some kind of booking key that was a combination of date and bed_id then it'd be a lot easier to scan for these. You could do a `WHERE booking_token IN (...)` and have it all indexed, performant, and concise. It takes some advance planning though to do it properly. `YYYY-MM-DD-bed_id` could work as a first pass.

Answer (score 0):

For your view code, I would try:

```
= week_calendar events: @monthly_reservations, attribute: :date do |date, appts|
  - current_user.beds.each do |bed|
    %p{style: "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; font-size: 10px;"}
      = [bed.name, @reservations[[date, bed.id]]].compact.join(":")
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidAldridge. Is this simply a refactor, or is there some type of performance enhancement I'm missing? I'll admit, my base Ruby knowledge isn't too high. Looks like I might need to open up POODR again! :)

Comment: @PatrickJones POODR FTW! It's a refactor to remove redundancy.