# Rails Design Pattern for Multiple Devise Log-Ins Managing One Set of Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

---

### EDIT: What's the design pattern for an app that does the following: A business sets up an account with the app. The business then creates "employees" in the app that can log in separately and CRUD the business's data, except for what their employer marks as off limits?

I've run into a problem with the hostel app. Here we go:

My app, a hostel management SaaS, has many users. These are hostels. The owner of the hostel signs up for my app via Devise. `current_user` is always the hostel itself.

Hostels `have_many` guests and each guest `belongs_to` a user(the hostel). These are people who call/email and want to spend a night in the hostel. Thanks a ton to everyone for helping me with the [availability calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787240/faster-database-where-for-rails-availability-calendar).

All is fine and dandy now. Normally, the hostel owner or manager logs into my app, books rooms, emails guests, sends invoices, upload financials, you name it. However, many have been requesting the ability to add employees that can log in separately and create reservations, send emails, etc, but NOT view financial info. Enter [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Here's where I'm stuck. It's easy enough to delegate abilities and authorizations. Devise also gives me the ability to set up multiple devise models. However, I'm stuck with how I can give the employee, once they log in, access to their employer's data. The `current_user.id` is going to be different than their employer's ID(the business that signed up), so how can I tell Devise to use the ID of their user?

```
class User
  has_many :employees
end

#should I do something like this?
class Employee
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :guests, :through => users
  has_many :reservations, :through => users
  has_many :rooms, :through => users
end
```

I thought about doing something like this below:

`current_user.id = current_employee.user.id`

The only problem is, it smells. There must be a better way. Once the employee logs in, everything is going to look the exact same as when their boss logs in(show all reservations, all guests, all emails, etc), the employee will just be restricted from certain areas.

[The same current_user on multiple models in devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549038/the-same-current-user-on-multiple-models-in-devise) is mostly workarounds and hacks. https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails seemed kind of in the right direction, but it's a bit too much for what I need. There must be a specific design pattern for this situation, but I can't seem to find it or even get Googling in the right direction.

Basically, how do Rails apps give their users the ability to create sub-users, and let those sub-users view the user's data with restrictions?

Any help getting my thoughts straightened out is much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this fits perfectly, but have you explored `devise groups` at all?

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything wrong with a simple override of the `current_user` method?

```
class ApplicationController
  def current_user
    super || current_employee&.user # safe operator for ruby 2.3+, otherwise `current_employee.try(:user)`
  end
end
```

Comment: My thoughts are that it shouldn't be a hack, and that I'm simply missing something glaringly obvious. How do other Rails SaaS apps let their user's create sub-users that have access to the user's data?

Comment: I would think ideally you'd have a difference between a group and its users, and the users would have roles (owner, employee etc...). the group might belong to one of the users as the owner, and the rest of the users belong to the group, but they're all users. current_user would apply universally, and every user would respond to user.group whether they were the owner or a member. Having the group and the owner be the same object probably complicates the situation @PatrickJones

Comment: What about something like: employee has_many guests through user?

Comment: Going with your group idea, how would you make sure that an employee creating a new guest record saves said object to the group, base everything off group_id instead of current_user.id? Employees don't have guests, beds, reservations, etc, just the business (the group) does.